# BeautifulSoup. Find and replace all instances of a word with one from my list

Tags: python, list, variables, beautifulsoup

I have a dictionary. The key is animals. The value is a list of different animals.
The size of the list and what the animals are will change with each application use.
For each animal in the list I want to search through my BeautifulSoup tree, find all occurrences of that animal and wrap it in a span tag/replace it with my span tagged animal

I am having trouble passing a variable into re.compile() to help with the search for these animals.

I am also wondering can you replace a single word in a string in BeautifulSoup if it has no tags nearby.

Windows 7, Python 2.7, BeautifulSoup 4
code is someting like this

```
for key, value in animals.iteritems():      #go through dict
    if key == 'ANIMALS':                    
        for name in value:                  #for name of animals in list
            animal_tag = soup.new_tag("span", id=key)   #create new tag with id=ANIMALS
            animal_tag.string = name                    #create new string with name of animal
            name = soup.find(text=re.compile(r'^%s$' % name)) 
            #find animals in doc - keeps throwing a none type error
            #replace animal in doc with new <span id="ANIMALS">animal>/span>
```

I appreciate any help that anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think it's simpler to just manipulate the raw HTML using `string.replace()`. If `text` is equal to the raw HTML:

```
for key, value in animals.iteritems():
    if key == 'ANIMALS':                    
        for name in value:
            text.replace(name,"<span id="+key+">"+name+"</span>")
```

Comment: tehsockz, Thanks for the quick reply. While this does not seem to be working for me it opens up the idea of working aournd the problem in a different way, which is always helpful. I appreciate the answer. Tried to upvote but lack the required reputation.

Comment: Scratch that. It is working. Just the logic of my programme needs work.